# Add package Syllable to Laravel 5.3 with autoloader not work

Tags: laravel, composer-php, autoload

I need use a package [Syllable](https://github.com/vanderlee/phpSyllable) on my project.

Install with composer, and class to autoload on my composer.json but get errors.

```
$ composer require vanderlee/syllable
```

Edit composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "vendor/vanderlee/syllable/classes"
        ],
```

Dump autoload

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

Now try with tinker

```
php artisan tinker
>>> namespace Abkrim\Setdart;
=> null
>>> 
>>> $syllable = new \Syllable('en-us');
=> Syllable {#670}
>>> echo $syllable->hyphenateText('Provide a plethora of paragraphs');
PHP warning:  file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/setdart/vendor/vanderlee/syllable/classes/../cache/syllable.en-us.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/setdart/vendor/vanderlee/syllable/classes/Syllable_Cache_FileAbstract.php on line 43
>>>
```

I know that any steep it's wrong. Which ?

Answer (score 0):

Faced same error: you just have to set the right path to cache folder for Syllable.

From doc:

```
// Set the directory where Syllable can store cache files
$syllable->getCache()->setPath(__DIR__ . '/cache');
```

With setPath() set an existing folder in your laravel app where Syllable can store cache files.